# Removing UIActivityIndicator inside a completion handler in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, block, completionhandler

I want to remove my activity indicator after completion of my block. So I did something like this.

```
func workflowSelected()
{
    self.btnWorkflow.setTitle(dm.workflowName, for: .normal)


    self.actIndApprover=UIActivityIndicatorView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: self.btnFirstApprover.frame.size.width-40, y: 5, width: 30, height: 30))
    self.actIndApprover.color=self.com.getfontColor()
    self.actIndApprover.startAnimating()
    self.btnFirstApprover.addSubview(self.actIndApprover)

    self.callingFirstApprovers() { (staus) in



        self.actIndApprover.stopAnimating()
        self.actIndApprover.removeFromSuperview()
        self.actIndApplyLeave.stopAnimating()
        self.actIndApplyLeave.removeFromSuperview()
        self.btnFirstApprover.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.approverClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        if(staus)
        {
            print("Approvers loaded")


             NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "approverSelected"), object: nil)



        }

        else
        {

            self.btnFirstApprover.setTitle(self.lan.getConvertedLanguageString(word: "First Approver"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

But this activityindicator never removes. Do I need to remove it on main thread? If so how can I do that. Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
func callingFirstApprovers(callback:@escaping(Bool)->Void)
{
    let strBindedParam="workflowId=\(dm.workflowID!)&requesterCode=\(dm.strEmpCode!)&levelId=1"
    let appendString=com.getServicePath(funcNAme: "workflow")
    restAPI.prepareUrl(baseUrl:dm.tenantUrl,appendString: appendString, bindedParams: strBindedParam, isAuthorized: true, method: .get, jsonBody: [:]) { (status) in

        if(status=="success")
        {
            self.com.removeProgress()
            print(self.dm.responseArray)
            self.arrayApproversFullArray=self.dm.responseArray


            if(self.dm.responseArray.count>0 && self.dm.responseArray != nil)
            {
                let obj=self.dm.responseArray[0] as! [String:Any]
                print("object approver------\(obj)")

                if let objApprover:Array<Any> = obj["Approvers"] as? Array<Any>
                {
                    if(objApprover.count>0)
                    {
                        self.dm.arrayFirstApprovers=objApprover
                        let approverInnerObj=objApprover[0] as! [String:Any]
                        print(objApprover)

                        if let strApproverCode=approverInnerObj["EmployeeCode"] as? Int
                        {
                            self.dm.strApproverCode=String(strApproverCode)

                        }

                        if let strApproverNAme=approverInnerObj["Name"] as? String
                        {
                            self.btnFirstApprover.setTitle(strApproverNAme, for: .normal)
                            self.dm.strApproverNAme=strApproverNAme
                        }

                        print("Approvers are more than 1")

                        callback(true)
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        callback(false)
                    }
                }



               callback(false)

            }

            else{
                callback(false)
            }




        }
        else
        {


            print(self.dm.errorMessage)
            self.com.showAlertMessage()
            callback(false)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, GUI changes has to be make on the main thread.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.actIndApprover.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Normally Xcode will give a warning in the console output.

Comment: I did like  this,, seems its calling multiple times. any reason for that?

Comment: this dispatch block is running multiple times

Comment: I don't know your code or the calls. It's not the Dispatch itself, that's your implementation thats called multiple times

Comment: I figured just now,, when initial time,, activity indicator disappear correctly,, but when I click the same btn it doesnt appear next time

Comment: You've added some breakpoints? Then you can see who is calling your completion